# How to Trigger Info or Error Banner for Adaptive Card in Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

So I was hoping to trigger an info/error banner for Adaptive Card in Teams, how?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Card button click submit request completion message appears in Adaptive Cards while sending a response to the bot.
The message can be of two types, **error or success**:

**Error:** When a response sent to the bot is unsuccessful, Something went wrong, Try again message appears.

**Success:** When a response sent to the bot is successful, Your response was sent to the app message appears.

If you don't want to display the success message, set the attribute **hide** to **true** in the msTeams **feedback** property.

Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-messages?tabs=dotnet#form-completion-feedback